# How the users Key strokes in loop as in REPL

Tags: r, loops, read-eval-print-loop

How can I capture the users Keyboard strokes in loop ( such "repeat" or "while(TRUE)" ) ?

I want something similar like REPL without disturbing streaming services within the loop.

sample pseudo code

```
While (TRUE) {
 # Capture terminal keyboard stroke
 # If Ctrl+Q then Stop, break
 # else Continue Loop services and monitoring other streams ( twitter for example )
}
```

So , I was wondering what type of connection should I use ? Text , raw , binary or stdin ?

and without interrupting the loop services . Any ideas , tricks , tips or hacks ?

Comment: The R console is REPL itself...can you give some idea as to what your intent is here?

Comment: True, the R console is REPL itself, which is handy. But in some case, in programming, you want collect data (_let us say every second_) from streaming services such sensors and web sensors.

At the same time, you want to be ready for the user interaction, such "1-start capture, 2-stop capture, 3-schedule a capture session, ctrl+Q Quit" and if entry made by the user the loop counitue with its assigned task and monitor the user key strokes beside the streams.

The Loop should be runnable from R console and Rscript.